# Как настроить плагин viewerjs?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы модальное окно плагина закрывалось, когда ты нажимаешь только на крестик, а не на области?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации https://github.com/fengyuanchen/viewerjs#backdrop

> **backdrop**
>
> - Type: `Boolean` or `String`
> - Default: `true`
>
> Enable a modal backdrop, specify `static` for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.

Вам нужно использовать опцию

```
{
  backdrop: 'static'
}
```